# Remove packages contain specific word in name

Tags: linux, fedora, rpm, yum

In Linux (Fedora), how I see all the installed packages which contain a certain words in the package name. Then, remove all these packages installed.

Comment: Which OS/distribution? There are different ways of package management...

Comment: @user2062950 
I am using fedora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fedora is an `RPM`-based distribution. So you'll want to use the `rpm` or `yum` commands.

To list installed: `yum list installed | grep <name>` or `rpm -a | grep <name>`

To remove a package: `rpm -e <package-name>` or `yum remove <package-name>`

Sources:

- [Fedora RPM Guide](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/)
- [Fedora `yum` wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Yum)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using a debian-based Linux (like Ubuntu or Mint, for example), you can do like this to search for `mysq`:

```
dpkg -l | grep mysq
```

and to get only the names

```
dpkg -l | grep mysq | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: I am using a fedora, it's rpm based.

Answer (score 2):

if you want remove all packages, containing a specific word, you don't need to pipe lists through grep or whatever. Just type

```
$ sudo yum remove "*word*"
```

If you want to review list of such packages before removing, then type

```
$ rpm -qa "*word*"
```

That's it.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I was trying variations of "yum list installed | grep -i {package name} | yum remove", but that didn't work. I knew there had to be a one-liner somewhere, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in linux, you can install programs in a variety of places. Most of the time, your rpm on your distro is responsible for removing all of the bits and pieces of a program. One solution, although this is fraught with danger, is to grep your usr/bin like this:

```
ls /usr/bin || grep 'some package name'
```

and pipe that to an rm-rf ... 'shuddurs'

A safer bet though is to just use apt-get uninstall 'someApp' much safter

Comment: Note that he is asking for packages, so what about packages that doesn't have a binary, or it is on `/usr/sbin` ?

Comment: this is kind of a fools errand, as a user can install that stuff where ever they like, i just pointed to a common dir. many packages are still directories and i think apt-get uninstalls them all the same